# How can I insert an initial element into Listview.builder

Tags: flutter

I want to show the `defaultUserContainer()` in case the stream is empty but also in case it's not, as an initial element of the list.
Currently. I can't seem to make either scenarios work. How can I design this better?

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 8.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "users",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87),
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 120,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: _firestore.collection('ts').where('userid', isEqualTo: widget.user.id).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                defaultUserContainer();  //If there's no users. tried returning it, or doing like it is here. never shows
                return Text("");
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot userDoc = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    if(index < snapshot.data.documents.length){
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {},
                          child: Container(
                            child: FittedBox(
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                elevation: 4.0,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      child: myDetailsContainer(userDoc),  //This guy works. it's just a more complicated defaultuserContainer()
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return ListTile(leading:defaultuserContainer()); //Doesn't show when there's users users (my goal is to always have this as an initial item)
                  }
                );
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ]
);
        
Widget defaultUserContainer() {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    child: Container(
      height: 120,
      width: 120,
      color: myColors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 65, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as the first/last element of your `ListView`/`GridView`/`Column`/etc.

Here is a simple example with a GridView:

[image]

### Full source code

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Random Generator',
      home: RandomGeneratorPage(),
    ),
  );
}

class RandomGeneratorPage extends HookWidget {
  final int max;
  final random = Random();

  RandomGeneratorPage({Key key, this.max = 20}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final numbers = useState<List<int>>([]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Random Generator')),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () =>
                numbers.value = [...numbers.value, random.nextInt(max)],
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue.shade100,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
          ...numbers.value
              .map(
                (number) => InkWell(
                  onTap: () => numbers.value =
                      numbers.value.where((x) => x != number).toList(),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(child: Text(number.toString())),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### In your case:

For your particular case, it would probably look like this: [**NOT TESTED**]

```
FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('ts')
          .where('userid', isEqualTo: widget.user.id)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue.shade100,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
          ...snapshot.data.documents.map(
            (doc) => Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => {},
                child: Container(
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: myDetailsContainer(
                                doc), //This guy works. it's just a more complicated defaultuserContainer()
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: needs some adjustements but for sure got me over the barrier. thank you!